# join rows with same index and keep other rows unchanged

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp

I have this data frame

```
df=

ID    join        Chapter  ParaIndex      text 
 0     NaN         1         0            I am test 
 1     NaN         2         1            it is easy 
 2     1           3         2            but not so
 3     1           3         3            much easy
```

I want to get this
(merge the column "text" with the same index in column "join" and reindex "ID" and "ParaIndex", rest without change)

```
dfEdited=

ID    join        Chapter  ParaIndex      text 
 0     NaN         1         0            I am test 
 1     NaN         2         1            it is easy 
 2     1           3         2            but not so much easy
```

I used this command

```
dfedited=df.groupby(['join'])['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
```

it only merges the row with the numerical index in column join and exclude row with non index

so I changed to this

```
dfedited=df.groupby(['join'],dropna=False)['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
```

here it merges all rows based on index join but it considers row with index NaN as one group therefore join them also to be group! however, I do not want to join them   ...any idea? many thanks

I also used this

```
dfedited=df.groupby(['join', "ParaIndex", "Chapter"],dropna=False  )['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str) )).reset_index()
```

it looks better as it has all columns, but no changes!!

Comment: I did that! 

```
dfedited=df.groupby(['join', "ParaIndex", "Chapter"],dropna=False  )['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str) )).reset_index()
```
it does not work

Comment: Have you finished? I suggest at least providing something executable for convenience.

Comment: yes, have look at my example

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can give an example of data and code. And do it step by step rather than just code it in one line without testing. It's hard to help you with this one-line code.

But the main idea is to use `merge(..., on='join')`

Comment: thank you, I edit my question with the example...can you have a look ?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

I solved that so;

```
dfEdited = df.assign(key=df['join'].ne(df['join'].shift()).cumsum()).groupby('key').agg({ "ParaIndex": 'first', "Chapter":'first','text':' '.join}).reset_index()
```